# javascript or jquery Input text number only and auto masking

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, input, numbers

I use javascript and jquery.

I want to make a masking template for

> `<input type="text">`

Which **accept numbers only** and **auto masking format for every number keyup** result.
 

 
The **masking format is : 99-99-99-99-[repeat format until last inputed number]**

Examples for valid input and result :

Inputed : 001234567890
 
Result : 00-12-34-56-78-90-
 

 
Inputed : 00[backspace]1234567890
 
Result : 01-23-45-67-89-0
 

 
Inputed : 00[backspace]1234567890
 
Result : 01-23-45-67-89-0
 

My current complete html working script with problems :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var count1=0;
var strPrev1 = '';
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#input1').keyup(function(e)
  {

//    Filter input text to accept only numbers , arrow movement, backspace, delete

    if ((e.keyCode == 8) ||  (e.keyCode == 46) || (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40) || (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105))
    {
      if ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105))
      {
        count1++;
//        if count1 % 2 = 0, add divider '-'
        if (count1 % 2 == 0) 
        { 
          $("#input1").val($("#input1").val()+'-');
        }
      } 
      if ((e.keyCode == 8) ||  (e.keyCode == 46))
      {
//      no idea what to do to keep the mask format 99-99-99-99-[repeat format until last inputed number] is it "count1--;" ?
      }
      strPrev1 = $("#input1").val();
    }
    else 
    {
//      replace input text value with previous accepted
      $("#input1").val(strPrev1);
    }
  });
});
</script>

<input name="input1" id="input1" type="text">

</body>
</html>
```

**Problems are how to keep it on the masking format 99-99-99-99-[repeat format until last inputed number] ? :** 
1. If the user is pressing delete, or backspace, the  will be changed. How to keep the masking format stand still ?
eg : 
Input : press 1234567890, move arrow left to 4, press delete, press 8, and move to the last line and press 12
My wrong result : 12-38-56-78-90-1-2
Correct result : 12-38-56-78-90-12-

2. If the user press the number in very fast, the input mask will be come weird... Sometimes it can become 999-9-99-99-99- and other masking format. Did not give me the desired masking format.. It should be still with the masking format : 99-99-99-99-[repeat format until last inputed number]. How to fix my current script ?
Eg:
Input : pres 123 in quick 
My wrong result : 123-
Correct result : 12-3



Any idea how to fix my script ?

PS : 
I already read the following links, still give me no idea to fix my script : 
[How to allow only numeric (0-9) in HTML  inputbox using jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/995183/how-to-allow-only-numeric-0-9-in-html-inputbox-using-jquery)
[Accept only numbers in Textbox - jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20119493/accept-only-numbers-in-textbox-jquery)
[jquery plugin to format text input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6904928/jquery-plugin-to-format-text-input)
[How to allow only numbers on a text input but allow commands with JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7488555/how-to-allow-only-numbers-on-a-text-input-but-allow-commands-with-javascript) 
[Only allow numbers in an input with javascript and allow copy and paste?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3257485/only-allow-numbers-in-an-input-with-javascript-and-allow-copy-and-paste) 
[Restrict input to number only on pasting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18311428/restrict-input-to-number-only-on-pasting)
[jQuery only digits in input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22256112/jquery-only-digits-in-input)
[Mask input for number - percent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7933505/mask-input-for-number-percent)
[Autotab input with javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15842375/autotab-input-with-javascript)
[Only allow Numbers in input Tage without Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12533508/only-allow-numbers-in-input-tage-without-javascript)
[How to force only numbers in a input, without Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17999067/how-to-force-only-numbers-in-a-input-without-javascript)
[Help to improve this javascript input mask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5120602/help-to-improve-this-javascript-input-mask)
[Why is my jquery input mask not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12324800/why-is-my-jquery-input-mask-not-working)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Done it by my self. Here is the answer :

```
<html>
 <head>
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js">
  </script>
</head>
<body>
<script>
var strPrev1 = '';
var strScore1 = '';
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $('#input1a').keyup(function(e)
  {
    if ( $("#input1a").val() == '' ) { $("#input0a").val(''); }
//    Filter input text to accept only numbers , arrow movement, backspace, delete
    if ((e.keyCode == 8) ||  (e.keyCode == 46) ||  (e.keyCode == 16) || (e.keyCode >= 35 && e.keyCode <= 40) || (e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105))
    {
      if ((e.keyCode >= 48 && e.keyCode <= 57) || (e.keyCode >= 96 && e.keyCode <= 105) || (e.keyCode == 8) ||  (e.keyCode == 46))
      {
        $("#input1a").val().replace("-","");
        strScore1 = $("#input1a").val().match(/.{1,2}/g);
        $("#input0a").val(strScore1.join().replace(/,/g , "-"));
      } 
      strPrev1 = $("#input1a").val();
    }
    else 
    {
//      replace input text value with previous accepted
      $("#input1a").val(strPrev1);
    }
  });
});
</script>

RESULT : <input name="input0a" id="input0a" type="text" style="width: 100%;" disabled>
SOURCE : <input name="input1a" id="input1a" type="text">
</body>
</html>
```

Use the **.match(/.{1,2}/g)** then **join()** it. finally, **.replace(/,/g , "-"))** the inputed string.

Answer (score 0):

If the user holds down a key the keyup event won't trigger, use a keypress event handler. Here's what I changed:

```
$('#input1').keypress(function(e)
```

...

```
if (count1 > 0 && count1 % 2 == 0) 
{ 
  $("#input1").val($("#input1").val()+'-');
}
count1++;
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/4xL36/)

Comment: Seems that it can only accept one character only.... And after I press number, backspace, and alphabet, it did not give me the result I wanted.

Comment: For example, if the user input 123465789, it will become 12-34-65-78-9. Your answer is only allowing one digit only... not auto masking... try to input 123[backspace]45, your result is 35 only. The correct result should be 12-45-.

Comment: Yea I noticed that after I posted, still needs some work i guess.

Comment: Sorry I can't understand your code here's what I tried http://jsfiddle.net/4xL36/1/

Comment: try to copy paste my complete html script into a real html file.

Comment: The accepted input is NUMBER only. and auto masking format into 99-99-99-99-[repeat until last number inputed]. if the input is not a number, then do nothing.