# How to create input number

Tags: php, jquery, css, ajax

How to create an input type number using this format?

Example :
when I start writing this number 1000, it should be generated to 1'000.

Example 2: 10000 to 10'000

Comment: Have a google for 'jquery input masking'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is it.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#num').keyup(function(){
    var numbers = $(this).val().replace("'","");
    var newNum = "";
    var digitCount = 0;
    
    for(var i = numbers.length-1; i>=0; i--){
      
      if(digitCount==3){
        newNum+="'";
        digitCount=0;
        }
      newNum += numbers.charAt(i);
      if($.isNumeric(numbers.charAt(i)))
         digitCount++;
      
    }
    $(this).val(newNum.split("").reverse().join(""));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="num">
```

Answer (score 1):

i'm using this plugin to make the number field auto masking. Very easy to use. Try this one. Give feedback if you can't implement it.

[Jquery number masking plugin repository](https://github.com/customd/jquery-number)

Examaple usage. After download plugin file, add this code into your js section code.

```
$('selector_element_to_mask').number(true, 0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this It will surly help you:

```
var num = 1000000;
console.log(formatNumber(num))
function formatNumber (num) {
    return num.toString().replace(/(\d)(?=(\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, "$1'")
}
```

DEMO with textfield 
http://jsfiddle.net/65y2bbrm/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for input masking posting a similar question though a bit different but I am sure it will point you in the right direction.

[javascript or jquery Input text number only and auto masking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23371840/javascript-or-jquery-input-text-number-only-and-auto-masking)